# Compiler error on including opengl/opengl.h

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, opengl

I have included the `opengl.framework` and `glut.framework` from `/systems/library/framework` into my xcode project. However when i import the header `import <OpenGl/OpenGl.h>`, i get an error no such file or directory. However in the framework group i can see the header files.

Can someone point out the rite way to include these frameworks in my iphone/ipad app project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header file usually is GL/gl.h, i.e.

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

On MacOS X the base directory naming breaks with this convention, there it is

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

Comment: No, i still get an error here. I want to know how to include the frameworks correctly into the project and do i import or include the header files.

Comment: I get the error `No such file or directory` in xcode 4 and i have added the frameworks. I want to know if the method to add the frameworks is correct or not.

Comment: @Praveen S:  don't know about Xcode 4 but in 3, you need to add them in the General tab of the target info as a linked library.

Comment: There is a different way to include for iphone apps. Though i will accept this answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: datenwolf, is this still true in 2019?  Most of the answers I see citing `#include <GL/gl.h>` are old.  I'm working on Ubuntu 16 and trying to port some code written for Mac OS X Darwin

Comment: @frank: Still true today. With the addition that Apple did deprecate OpenGL on macOS and tries to push people to use Metal. My recommendation: Use [https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK](MoltenVK] to have Vulkan on top of Metal. And if you want to stick to OpenGL then [Zink](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2018/10/31/introducing-zink-opengl-implementation-vulkan/) on top of Vulkan to get OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  To clarify, I'm on Ubuntu.  Does that change your recommendation?  Just need `#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>` and `#include <OpenGL/CGLTypes.h>` to work; here's the stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/neonb88/3c21e7086ecfee180a589c2c5de16004

Comment: On Linux is is guaranteed (by the Linux Software Base specification; Desktop profile) that the include path is `GL/gl.h`, so you'll have to use the suggested preprocessor `#ifdef`/`#else`/`#endif` dispatch. `CGLTypes.h` is specific to macOS, No idea why whatever you try to compile tries to pull that in in a Linux environment. The equivalent would be X11/GLX or EGL. But that's not really an OpenGL problem, but a build configuration problem.